# Using \footcite and \cite with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, biber

I collected a lot of references in an external bib-file, where I keep both references and resources, along side with cite-sources and bibliography items. Resources and Links shall go to the footnote area of each page, while references should appear at the References-pages of the whole document.

There is no problem to create normal footnotes and citation in general works well. But I am unable to get `\footcite{...}` working as I want. It either shows just a sign with a `hyperref` to the last page, where the reference is mentioned. When I set `style=verbose` in the usepackage section, the footnote shows the whole reference-info but all the other `\cite` notes in the text too, what clearly isn't what I intend.
Because of special formatting and other advantages I use the `biber` backend.

```
\documentclass[12pt,hyperref]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Max Maximus}
\title{}
\bibliography{somebibfile}
\pdfoutput=1

\begin{document}
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor\cite{colomb_ontology_2007}
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis\footcite{handa_nepomuk_2013} 
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@book{colomb_ontology_2007,
    title = {Ontology and the semantic web},
    isbn = {9781586037291},
    pagetotal = {258},
    publisher = {{IOS} Press},
    author = {Colomb, Robert M.},
    date = {2007}
}
@letter{handa_nepomuk_2013,
    title = {Nepomuk in 4.13 and beyond},
    url = {https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/nepomuk/2013-December/004858.html},
    type = {E-mail},
    author = {Handa, Vishesh},
    urldate = {2014-12-01},
    date = {2013-12-12},
}
```

To summarize:

- I want a footcite to contain the full cite string as it would appear in the bibliography section
- Sources cited with footcite shouldn't appear in the printbibliograhy section
- \cites should use the normal style with a number to the item in the printbibliography section (of course with the later option to change the abbreviation appearance)

Footnote appearance I wish

[image: Footnote appearance I wish]

Footnote appearance without style=verbose (I don't want this)

[image: Footnote appearance without style=verbose (I don't want this)]

Normal cite, how it should be without style=verbose

[image: Normal cite, how it should be without style=verbose]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @moewe Yes, that would probably solve it

Comment: Maybe using `\footfullcite` instead of `\footcite` (together with the `numeric` style) is for you then.

Comment: @moewe Oh thank you very much, how could I have overlooked that! Never used it until now. If you convert your comment to an answer, I'd mark it as solved: BTW removing it from printbibliography, will be another issue, but I have seen ways to do it [here](http://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=fullcite+remove+from+printbibliography&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=d36yVN7VJ9TH8geDxIHYBw) .

Comment: I had missed the point about removing it from `\printbibliography`, sorry. In this case, I think it is more convenient to come up with a new command. Give me a few minutes, maybe I can come up with something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to have a full citation in footnotes, you can go with `\footfullcite`, but if you also want to exclude entries cited in footnotes from the bibliography, it is probably more convenient to define a new command that does both of these things at the same time.

We first set up a category called `skipbibliography`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
```

Then we define `\myfootcite` to add the cited entry to the `skipbibliography` category and cite it in the `\footfullcite` manner (this command is just `\footfullcite` [from `biblatex.def`, ll. 2115-2121](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2115-L2121), with the `\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%` line added)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

If you now want to print the bibliography, use

```
\printbibliography[notcategory=skipbibliography]
```

to exclude entries of the `skipbibliography` category.

If you want to use a `numeric` citation style, you will want to use the `defernumbers` option to make sure that the entries appearing in the bibliography are numbered consecutively (without the option, the skipped entries would also be "counted", which would lead to jumps in the numbering since they are excluded from the bibliography).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \cite{cicero} dolor\myfootcite{wilde} sit amet. 

\printbibliography[notcategory=skipbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. It would help even more if you could explain or reference what the names in `DeclareCiteCommand` are, such as `prenote`, `entrytype` etc.

Comment: For example, it seems that  options like `defernumbers` are important. Without it the reference in footnote would be the [2] and the next reference if exists would be numbered [3].

Comment: @konpsych I added a passage about `defernumber` (more explanation can be found in the `biblatex` documentation). I also added a link to the original definition of `\footfullcite` that I modified here. All used macros are either defined in `biblatex.def` or documented in the `biblatex` manual.