# Using \footcite and \cite with \printbibliography without skipping numbers in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow-up question to [Using \footcite and \cite with \printbibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222615/using-footcite-and-cite-with-printbibliography/385615#385615)

I have to have two kind of references in my document. Footnotes that reference web sources and the standard references at the end of the document.

The goal is, that the footnote references do not appear in the bibliography. Therefore, I used the [referenced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222615/using-footcite-and-cite-with-printbibliography/385615#385615) approach which works fine. The only problem is, that the references in the bibliography skip numbers. Is there any way around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbib}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbib}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \cite{handa_nepomuk_2013} test\myfootcite{colomb_ontology_2007} dolor\myfootcite{adams1995hitchhiker} sit amet. 

\printbibliography[notcategory=skipbib]
\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}

@book{colomb_ontology_2007,
    title = {Ontology and the semantic web},
    isbn = {9781586037291},
    pagetotal = {258},
    publisher = {{IOS} Press},
    author = {Colomb, Robert M.},
    date = {2007}
}

@letter{handa_nepomuk_2013,
    title = {Nepomuk in 4.13 and beyond},
    url = {https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/nepomuk/2013-December/004858.html},
    type = {E-mail},
    author = {Handa, Vishesh},
    urldate = {2014-12-01},
    date = {2013-12-12},
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Its much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `biblatex` with the option `defernumbers`. This was indeed a problem with my original answer. I have fixed that as well.

MWE (`filecontents` will overwrite an existing `.bib` file with the same name without warning)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}

@book{colomb_ontology_2007,
    title = {Ontology and the semantic web},
    isbn = {9781586037291},
    pagetotal = {258},
    publisher = {{IOS} Press},
    author = {Colomb, Robert M.},
    date = {2007}
}

@letter{handa_nepomuk_2013,
    title = {Nepomuk in 4.13 and beyond},
    url = {https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/nepomuk/2013-December/004858.html},
    type = {E-mail},
    author = {Handa, Vishesh},
    urldate = {2014-12-01},
    date = {2013-12-12},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \cite{handa_nepomuk_2013} test\myfootcite{colomb_ontology_2007} dolor\myfootcite{adams1995hitchhiker} sit amet. 

\printbibliography[notcategory=skipbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped example output]