# Full bibliography does not show the not referenced citations in Document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, multiple-citations

I asked how to make a double bibliography type in this question.
Out of that came a cool code sample in wich i didn't notice a special circumstance. If i do not reference a item it does not show up at the full bibliography. I wold like to see all items writen in the .bib file in the full bibliography regardless if its referenced (with `\cite{ref1}`) in the document or not.

here is the MWE koleygr developed with me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addbibresource{./latexfiles/ref.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and %\cite{adams}. 

\lipsum[1-8]
here is a last footcite \cite{einstein}

\printbibliography[notcategory=skipbibliography]

\pagebreak %<- Remove these lines if you dont nead a bibliography at the end
\printbibliography %<- 2md line to remove

\end{document}
```

And in a subfolder file named "latexfiles/ref.bib"

```
@Book{Goossens,
author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and
Samarin, Alexander},
title = {The LaTeX Companion},
edition = {1},
publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
location = {Reading, Mass.},
year = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
title = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
author = {Douglas Adams},
series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
year = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
author = {Albert Einstein},
title = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
[{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
journal = {Annalen der Physik},
volume = {322}, 
}
```

you can se i removed \cite{adams} as example. It does not apear in the full bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer with biber (I changed bibtex to biber and added '\nocite{*}' befor last printbibliography. See the comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex} %<- changed "bibtex" to "biber"
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addbibresource{./latexfiles/ref.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and %\cite{adams}. 

\lipsum[1-8]
here is a last footcite \cite{einstein}


\nocite{*} %<-Added this command to "cite un-cited citations" (lol)
\pagebreak 
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes works. great thanks again!
for following information: remove the line: \printbibliography[notcategory=skipbibliography] 
this line still prints a doubled bib and does not show all bib items.